# German Umlauts on US keyboard

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, manjaro, special-characters

I am using a US keyboard layout because it's more convenient for programming, but since I am German I need the German umlauts for texting. (Umlauts like `ÄäÖöÜü`)
I am running Manjaro with KDE.

I want to get press

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> -> `ü`

and

<kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> -> `Ü`

I tried copying the US keymap from /usr/share/kbd/keymap and adding

```
alt keycode 32 = odiaeresis
```

to get the `ü` to work, but it didn't do anything.
I queried the keycode 32 by entering

```
xmodmap -pk | grep -i o
```

which returned:

```
32         0x006f (o)      0x004f (O)      0x006f (o)      0x004f (O)
```

Comment: With a Compose Key enabled as AltGr you can AltGr u " and get ü. (Similar patterns work for many accented characters or other characters not available on one's keyboard - ß ø æ à ñ §, etc.) Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Do you have a US keyboard, or are you using a german keyboard just with US layout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`setxkbmap 'de(us)'`

This is a good in-between solution. It is actually the US-layout with only a few modifications. File is `symbols/de`:

```
xkb_symbols "us" {
    include "us"

    name[Group1]="German (US, with German letters)";

    key <AC01> { [           a,          A, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AC02> { [           s,          S,     ssharp,      U1E9E ] };
    key <AC10> { [   semicolon,      colon, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AC11> { [  apostrophe,   quotedbl, adiaeresis, Adiaeresis ] };
    key <AD03> { [           e,          E,   EuroSign,   EuroSign ] };
    key <AD07> { [           u,          U, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AD09> { [           o,          O, odiaeresis, Odiaeresis ] };
    key <AD11> { [ bracketleft,  braceleft, udiaeresis, Udiaeresis ] };
    key <AE03> { [           3, numbersign,    section,    section ] };
    key <AE11> { [       minus, underscore,     ssharp,   question ] };

    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};
```

The `ralt_` should be the `AltGr` key. The umlaute are on the letters and on the "german" place (right side).

With `include "us"` this is more `us(de)` than `de(us)`.

### € ßẞ ÄÖÜ § äöü

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was exactly what I was searching for. I still need to do some more modification to it (like removing ß on - key and so on), but that's a very good start :)

Comment: `removing ß on - key` I don't use it, but it does not disturb at all, because it needs the AltGr key. That is the good part of this soultion. Negative is: if you type a bit more, then you will want the `äöü` available directly, without AltGr. But that is where `;` and `[` and `'`are sitting, and just because of these programming keys you (and me) want the US layout...

Comment: That ß on - was just an example. I want to add some more shortcuts which can be helpful for programming, like -> on alt gr + . (for fast lambdas in java) and so on. I never had a problem with using alt gr for umlauts. I honestly prefer it over having an extra key for it. I searched a lot of text messages to find the needed characters to make this post and again noticed how rarely I am using them

Answer (score 1):

For Debian Linux (I'm running bookworm) there is already a variant that provides a western europe mapping called `altgr-weur`.

```
setxkbmap -rules evdev -model evdev -layout us -variant altgr-weur
```

An excerpt of this existing variant is here (only keys described by the OP, see `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` for more):

```
   key <AD03> { [         e,          E,      ediaeresis,        Ediaeresis ] };
   key <AD07> { [         u,          U,      udiaeresis,        Udiaeresis ] };
   key <AD08> { [         i,          I,      idiaeresis,        Idiaeresis ] };
   key <AD09> { [         o,          O,      odiaeresis,        Odiaeresis ] };
   key <AE05> { [         5,    percent,        EuroSign,          sterling ] };
   key <AE08> { [ 8,           asterisk,          ssharp,        dead_greek ] };
```

Only the paragraph (`section`) is missing from this mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I recently navigated a similar challenge and wanted to get umlauts working
in the command line on my Debian laptop. 
I found the solution [from this very cool blog post](https://www.blunix.com/blog/using-german-umlauts-on-us-layout-keyboards.html). Here is what I did:

1. Identify your right Alt key's keycode with `xev`:

   Launch a terminal, type `xev`, press your right Alt key,
   and copy the "keycode" that it shows when you press it.
2. Create a `.xmodmap` file in your home directory
   and fill it with the following:

   ```
   keycode 135 = Mode_switch
   keysym e = e E EuroSign
   keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
   keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
   keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
   keysym s = s S ssharp
   ```
3. Apply the configuration by executing `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` in the terminal.
4. Automate the setup on shell startup:

   Incorporate the `xmodmap ~/.xmodmap` command into your `~/.bashrc`
   to have it automatically executed each time you open a shell.